# Pytorch MaskedTensor: TypeError: mask must have dtype bool

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I use MaskedTensor(). I give it the mask:

```
MaskedTensor(features[18][:, :, None], (features[18][:, :, None] != 0).bool())
```

`(features[18][:, :, None] != 0).bool().type()` gives me `torch.cuda.BoolTensor`. But I running into the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[40], line 3
          1 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
          2     print(f'Starting epoch {epoch+1}')
    ----> 3     train_epoch(model, optimizer, dataset_train, batch_size=train_batch_size, 
          4                 shuffle=True, print_loss_every_n_batches=500, device=device)
          6     val_roc_auc = eval_model(model, dataset_val, batch_size=val_batch_szie, device=device)
          7     es(val_roc_auc, model)
    
    ...
         30 model.train()
         32 for batch in tqdm(train_generator, desc='Training'):
    ---> 34     output = torch.flatten(model(batch['transactions_features'], batch['product']))
         36     batch_loss = loss_function(output, batch['label'].float())
         38     batch_loss.backward()
    
  ...
       1189         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
    -> 1190     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
       1191 # Do not call functions when jit is used
       1192 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []
    ...
        208     or data.dtype == torch.int64
        209 ):
        210     raise TypeError(f"{data.dtype} is not supported in MaskedTensor.")
    
    TypeError: mask must have dtype bool.

numpy==1.23.1
torch==1.13.0+cu116
torchaudio==0.13.0+cu116
torchvision==0.14.0+cu116
```

So I can't understand, where the problem is. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't match the error message where the problem occurs. You should look at line 34 instead: likely on the 2nd argument `output = torch.flatten(model(batch['transactions_features'], batch['product']))`

Comment: No, for the second argument I did’t create Mask